# Trace derivative

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, trace

I started reading Stephen Adler's book, "Quantum Theory as an Emergent phenomenon". He introduces 'Trace dynamics', and defines the following, 'Trace derivative': "Given the trace of a Polynomial $P$ constructed from a non-commuting matrix or operator variables, one can define  a derivative of complex number $\mbox{Tr} P$, as :

$$\delta \mbox{Tr} P = \mbox{Tr}\frac{\delta \mbox{Tr} P}{\delta O}\delta O$$

**Question 1:** How to make sense out of this?, I don't understand this definition at all, and how does one usually rigorously define derivative with respect to an Operator?.

He provides, the following example, to understand this derivative. Let, $P$ is a Bosonic monomial ( that is built out of matrices having elements which are products of an even number of Grassmannian elements) containing a single factor of $O$. $P = AOB$, $A$ and $B$ generally do not commute with each other or $O$.

Then - $\delta P =A(\delta O)B$, taking trace, using cyclic permutation gives-

$\delta \mbox{Tr} P = \epsilon_{B} \mbox{Tr} BA\delta O$, ($\epsilon_{B}$ = $+1$ when Operator is Bosonic, and $-1$ when Fermionic, i.e Matrices having elements which are products of odd number of Grassmannian elements), then -

$$\frac{\delta \mbox{Tr} P}{\delta O} = \epsilon_{B} BA$$

**Question 2:** I don't understand, this last step here, how did the trace disappear?

Comment: A 2012 paper revisiting the 2004 book's proposal is freely available here; https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/361/1/012002/pdf

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix-valued
scalar function $\phi(\mathbf{X})$.
By definition, the differential
$d\phi$ is related to the gradient by
$$
d\phi
=
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
:
d\mathbf{X}
$$
where $:$ denotes the Frobenius inner product.
Because
$\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B} 
= \mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B})$, it holds

$$
d\phi
=
\mathrm{tr}
\left[
\left(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{X}}
\right)^T
d\mathbf{X}
\right]
$$
This is I think the simple reason of the expression you give.